# how can i set a link in website to button

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm do programm with gui. I need assign to button "Help" website link. When you click this button, the browser should open and go to the specified link. It's posible? 
[this is what the program looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZKfH.png)

```py
self.help = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
self.help.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 131, 23))
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setFamily("Arial")
font.setPointSize(10)
self.help.setFont(font)
self.help.setObjectName("help")
```

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself bette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open url in browser use `QDesktopServices.openUrl` static method. See attached example.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDesktopServices
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl


class UrlOpenWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn = QPushButton("Open url", self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.open_url)

    def open_url(self):
        QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widg = UrlOpenWidget()
    widg.show()
    app.exec_()
```